# How to override set data method when using custom class objects in grid's dataprovider

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid, overriding

*** Newbie Alert ***

I have an AdvancedDataGrid with 5 columns. The second column, with header Labels, needs to be able to contain multiple lines in each cell.

Initially, my grid's dataprovider was defined as follows:

```
[Bindable]
public var mappedTagsArray:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( [ 
    { name: "garbage-garbage", semanticTags: "garbage-flirt\ngarbage-garbage\ngarbage-noise\ngarbage-profanity", exitStrategy: "Fallback", confirmationMode: "IF NECESSARY", confirmationPromptlet: "cp5" }, 
    { name: "report-sim", semanticTags: "enquire-sim\nreport-sim", exitStrategy: "Direct", confirmationMode: "NEVER", confirmationPromptlet: "cp6" }
] );
```

The Columns label was defined as follows, with an inlined TextArea component to handle the multiple lines in one cell:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn id="semanticTags" headerText="Labels" dataField="semanticTags" editable="false">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <mx:HBox horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
                                             top="0" bottom="0" right="0" left="0">
                <fx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        import com.nuance.csportal.mw_api.CallerIntent;
                        public function get value() : String
                        {
                            return ta_labels.text;
                        }
                        override public function set data(value:Object):void
                        {
                            super.data = value;
                            ta_labels.text = value.semanticTags;
                        }
                    ]]>
                </fx:Script>
                <!-- BUG: Scroll bar is fixed in one location; does not move with resizing of cell -->
                <s:TextArea id="ta_labels" heightInLines="2" editable="false" borderVisible="false"
                                                    horizontalScrollPolicy="auto" verticalScrollPolicy="auto" contentBackgroundAlpha="0"
                                                    top="0" bottom="0" right="0" left="0"/>
            </mx:HBox>                                      
        </fx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
```

In this scenario, the semanticTags multiple lines are displayed in the Labels column's cell.

---

Now I've created a custom ActionScript class called CallerIntent:

```
package com.nuance.csportal.mw_api
{
    import mx.controls.List;

    public class CallerIntent
    {
        public function CallerIntent( id:int, name:String, semanticTags:Array, exitStrategy:String, confirmationMode:String, confirmationPromptlet:String )
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.semanticTags = semanticTags;
            this.exitStrategy = exitStrategy;
            this.confirmationMode = confirmationMode;
            this.confirmationPromptlet = confirmationPromptlet;
        }

        public var id:int;
        public var name:String;
        public var semanticTags:Array;
        public var exitStrategy:String;
        public var confirmationMode:String;
        public var confirmationPromptlet:String;
    }
}
```

And in my init() method which is called upon creationComplete of my form, I populate my grid's dataprovider:

```
public function init( event:Event ):void
{
    var st1:Array = new Array( "garbage-flirt", "garbage-garbage", "garbage-noise", "garbage-profanity" );
    var st2:Array = new Array( "enquire-sim", "report-sim" );
    var ci1:CallerIntent = new CallerIntent( 1, "garbage-garbage", st1, "Fallback", "IF NECESSARY", "cp1" );
    var ci2:CallerIntent = new CallerIntent( 2, "report-sim", st2, "Direct", "NEVER", "cp2" );

    mappedTagsArray.addItem( ci1 );
    mappedTagsArray.addItem( ci2 );
}
```

In this scenario, my app crashes in the override set data method at
     ta_labels.text = value.semanticTags;
with
     Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

This is true – value remains null when I’m using an ArrayCollection of CallerIntent objects as opposed to the ArrayCollection of unnamed objects (in this case, value will hold the unnamed Object).

I tried changing the function’s signature to
     override public function set data(value:CallerIntent):void
and got Incompatible Override.

Any ideas?  Thanks!
Bonnie

Comment: Wait, what are you trying to do exactly?  Just get a label to span 2 rows? You're not being very clear in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed my problem.
My grid's dataprovider is getting populated AFTER the overridden set data method is first called.
Hence I just had to put

```
 if ( value != null )
```

around this code.

Comment: More likely the dataprovider is not instantiated when you are assigning it. var myDP:myDataProvider = new myDataProvider();